# How do I solve a coupled system of differential equations containing time-varying parameters in Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing, ode

I'm trying to solve a system of three coupled ODEs that contain several parameters that vary with time (in Python). I've read other stack exchange answers to this and have tried to follow them carefully (using ODEint), but I'm still getting output that jumps all over the place.

Just wondering if there is an ODE solver in Python designed to deal with parameters that change with time. The final system I need to solve is six equations with about 15 parameters each (reaction rates... modeling Big Bang Nucleosynthesis). Any help would be amazing. Thank yoU!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri May  3 12:42:24 2019
"""

import scipy.integrate as integ
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Initate time array
n=200
t0=0.1
tf=100
time_vec = np.linspace(t0,tf,n)

#Initiate Nuclide Abundances 
X_n0 = 0.5
X_p0 = 0.5
X_D0 = 0.0
X0_vec = (X_n0, X_p0, X_D0)

#define functions of changing parameters
def a(t):
    return np.sqrt(t)

def rho_b(t, a):
    return 1 / (a(t) ** 3)

#define functions of changing reaction rates
def brac_pn(t, rho_b):
    return 2.5E4 * rho_b(t, a)


#Define function to plug into ODEint
def EvolveDensity(X, t, a, rho_b, brac_pn):
    dX_n_dt = (X[0] * X[1]) + (brac_pn(t, rho_b) * X[2] )
    dX_p_dt = (X[0] * X[1]) + (brac_pn(t, rho_b) * X[2] )
    dX_D_dt = - (X[0] * X[1]) + (brac_pn(t, rho_b) * X[2] )
    return [dX_n_dt, dX_p_dt, dX_D_dt]


#Solve Ode through time
Densities = integ.odeint(EvolveDensity, X0_vec, time_vec, args=(a, rho_b, brac_pn))


plt.plot(time_vec,Densities[:,0])
plt.plot(time_vec,Densities[:,1])
plt.plot(time_vec,Densities[:,2])
```

Comment: Is it correct that the derivatives are the same up to the sign in the last? Especially that the first two are identical? How do you handle the resulting possible dynamical blow-up? // Do you intend to vary the time-dependent functions? If not, then the are global "constants" (as function objects), it does not really make sense to include them as parameters.

Comment: If you play with the time interval you can find that the blow-up, divergence to minus infinity, happens before `t=0.100045`, could you discuss the original problem and how you justify the implemented approximation?